# Почему при переходе по ссылке из панели разработчика на приложение пишет "файл не найден"?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

Подскажите, пож-ста.
Опубликовал приложение для альфа-тестирования в гугл маркете еще 9 ноября. С тех пор пишет, что файл не найден. Т.е. протестировать я его не могу. Загрузил вторую версию для альфа-тестирования. Опять пишет, что файл не найден.
Уже опускаются руки. Мне нужно опубликовать приложение. Все настроено, готово. Хочу протестировать. В эмуляторе идеально. В чем здесь может быть проблема? Может кто-то сталкивался.

Comment: Где и кто пишет, что файл не найден? Опишите проблему более детально.

Comment: При переходе по ссылке в гугл плей, где должно быть размещено мое приложение для альфа тестирования пишет "файл не найден". Т.е. группа тестировщиков не может его скачать и протестировать. Не понимаю в чем может быть проблема.

Comment: Для альфа-тестирования, вроде бы, нужно добавлять в белый список аккаунты тех, кому приложение должно быть доступно. Или же где-то отметить, что тестирование открытое.

Comment: Вот инструкции - [Как провести тестирование](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=ru).